# rostopic pub geometry_msgs/PoseArray example

Tags: ros, rostopic--pub, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anybody give me an example of geometry_msgs/PoseArray message using rostopic pub? I keep on getting errors when i try and interpret the syntax from the ROS documentation, a solid example would be really helpful.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251586/rostopic-pub-geometry_msgs/posearray-example/) by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2017-01-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's an example with the Bash multiline syntax:

```
rostopic pub /test geometry_msgs/PoseArray "header:
  seq: 0
  stamp:
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
poses:
- position:
    x: 1.0
    y: 2.0
    z: 3.0
  orientation:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 0.0
- position:
    x: 4.0
    y: 5.0
    z: 6.0
  orientation:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 0.0"
```

Here's an example using the [YAML command line dictionary](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/YAMLCommandLine#Command-line_and_messages_.28dictionaries.29) syntax:

```
rostopic pub /test geometry_msgs/PoseArray "{header: auto, poses: [{position: [1,2,3]}, {position: [4,5,6]}]}"\
```

You can also use the `-f` option to read the message contents from a YAML file. For example, imagine `tmp.yaml` had the following contents:

```
poses:
- position:
    x: 1.0
    y: 2.0
    z: 3.0
  orientation:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 0.0
- position:
    x: 4.0
    y: 5.0
    z: 6.0
  orientation:
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 0.0
```

This could be published using

```
rostopic pub /test geometry_msgs/PoseArray -f tmp.yaml
```

Note that when reading from a file if you would like to publish the message continuously at a set rate, you need to have multiple messages in the file separated by `---` lines.

Personally when the messages get this complicated, I generally just write a short Python script to publish the desired message at whatever rate I want to avoid having to mess with this complicated syntax at the command line.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2